# Adjusting screen brightness of a Thinkpad-T14 Laptop does not work on a freshly installed Ubuntu (both on 18.04 and 20.04)

Tags: lenovo, brightness, thinkpad

The title is self explaining. I can not change screen brightness of my laptop which is Lenovo Thinkpad T14. I tried it with fresh installations of Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. None of them is working. Right now I decided to stick to 18.04. Has anyone managed to solve this?

**Hint:** Some outputs that might be helpful:

```
$ uname -r
--> 5.4.0-54-generic

$ dpkg --print-architecture
--> amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but I've also been having the same issue. I fixed it today but using the `Ubuntu Mainline Kernel` Installer to install kernel `5.9.3` which solved my brightness control issues in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Yes, I have solved my problem by updating to a new kernel. in my case it was 5.9.0